# Defining a Topology via Closed Sets

Tags: general-topology

I'm struggling with a question about defining a topology in terms of closed rather than open sets. If we define a closed set as a set of the form $[a,b]$, where $a$ and $b$ are finite and rational, $a<b$, and say that finite unions and infinite intersections of closed sets are also closed, what do open sets look like? Obviously $(-\infty, a) \bigcup (b, \infty)$ is open, and my intuition is that eventually I should be able to show that $(a, b)$ is open for rational a, b and that this is therefore the standard topology.
I tried to proceed by essentially moving backwards from showing that $[a,b]$ is closed with the standard definition of open sets, showing that $(-\infty, a) \bigcup (b,\infty)$ open $\implies \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} (-n, a) \bigcup (b, n) $ open, but this is where I stalled, since unless I'm wrong, this doesn't imply that $(b, n)$ is open for arbitrary b and n. Is this just a bad way to go about this? Am I off in my assumption of what the topology will look like? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Topology_Defined_by_Closed_Sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition is problematic. First of all, you define $[a,b]$ to be closed under very strict condition, and then you require more. You should write that the *basic closed sets* are $[a,b]$ when $a<b$ are rational numbers.

However if you require them both to be finite, then $\Bbb R$ is not closed anymore. Because $\Bbb R$ cannot be written as a finite union of finitely many finite intervals. So you have to allow the endpoints to be infinite in this case.

Once you have that, it's easy to show that $(a,b)$ is open.

Comment: You're right, that is obviously problematic -- sorry about the mistake. The question I'm working off of does in fact specify that $\Bbb R$ and $\emptyset$ are closed (which makes me wonder why it matters that $a$ and $b$ are finite). I can pretty easily use DeMorgan to see that this implies that arbitrary unions and finite intersections of open sets are open, but I can't get a sense for what the open sets look like other than $(-\infty, a) \bigcup (b, \infty)$.

Comment: @Henry, but the issue is that if you don't allow $a,b$ to be infinite then you can't generate any infinite closed intervals, which are certainly *closed*. In fact you can even require in your "basic" closed sets that one of the endpoints is always infinite. (I'm using quotation marks because I'm not quite sure what the common definition of a basis for closed sets, if it's shrinking the sets like with open sets, or enlarging them -- as everything else is switched.)

Comment: Why are those certainly closed? I'm sorry, I'm just a little confused by your response. I'm not assuming that this is a description of a certain, recognizable topology, I'm trying to figure out what this topology looks like, so if I can't generate infinite closed intervals with finite unions/infinite intersections, then they aren't closed.

Comment: Henry, Do you agree that the complement of an open set is closed?

Comment: Yes, but only because in this case open sets are defined as the complement of closed sets, so the complement of the complement of a closed set is closed.

Comment: Henry, either you get a topology which is **not** the standard topology on $\Bbb R$, which is fine; or you have a mistake. The point is that if you want $(0,\infty)$ to be open, then $[-\infty,0]$ has to be closed.

Comment: Ok, then this doesn't really answer my question. I see that I don't in fact have the standard topology on $\Bbb R$, but I'm still having trouble identifying what open sets might look like. Are they limited to those of the form $(-\infty, a) \bigcup (b, \infty)$?

Comment: No. What happens when you take the complement of $[0,1]\cup[2,3]$?

Comment: Ok, duh, sorry. So open sets are going to look like any "normal" open set in the standard topology $(a, b)$ or a finite union/infinite intersection of sets like that, with "tails" of $(-\infty, c)$ and $(d, \infty)$ for arbitrary c and d?

Comment: Yes, an open set is going to have the form $(-\infty,a_0)\cup(a_1,a_2)\cup\ldots\cup(a_{n-2},a_{n-1})\cup(a_n,\infty)$.

Comment: That was what I thought originally, but I was suspicious that there might be some union/intersection trick to lose the "tails", so to speak. Thanks for the help and the speedy response!

Comment: Sure, you're just lucky I have a [practically] unlimited cellular plan; the phone lines are down with no current expectation for the problem to be fixed. :-P